# How to delete my answer in the post??

Tags: discussion

Sometimes i might not answer the questions in a clear form.And so if someother person gives the brief and clear answer.I would like to delete my own answer,so that the post might contain the most relevant answer which is useful for all other users to get the right answer.But when i click delete,the answer is not deleted instead it show's a undelete option.Why??

Comment: When you refresh the page, the answer is shown with a different background and the deletion status (the screenshot in Marco's answer, below).  It is slightly confusing that clicking 'delete' without refreshing only changes the link to 'undelete'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer *is* indeed deleted. However, this site is part-wiki so things are never truly deleted. Owners of the content (Like yourself) and certain privileged users can view deleted questions and answers.

[image]

The fact that you;re seeing an undelete options means the content was removed from public viewing for that post.

Comment: What you mean by priviged users??Do you mean registerd users?or the users with more reputation??

Comment: @Karthick87 From what I can tell - 10k Users and Moderators